# Display raw html in tinymce that is wrapped in code/pre, not rendered

Tags: html, laravel, tinymce, code-snippets

I am using tinymce as my wysiwyg editor in laravel app.
Everytime i create an article that contains code such as html meta tag or title etc wrapped in code/pre. Once i reload the page to edit, it disappears. If i set the encode raw then it does not disappear in backend but displays all raw html in front end. I want to display only raw html in frontend that is wrapped in code/pre. I dont know how many days i need more to solve it? All i want is to display html code in my blog, raw html code that is wrapped in code/pre, not rendered! This is my thread in stackoverflow. Please help.

[code snippet disappears only plain text remains in tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411304/code-snippet-disappears-only-plain-text-remains-in-tinymce?noredirect=1#comment66161128_39411304)

I will delete the previous thread once i solve it, sorry to post similar question.

Comment: Same problem here. Anybody ??